# Material UI List, how do I "renumber" the list (eg 1,2,5,6,7,8... renumbering 3 -> 5)?

Tags: list, material-ui, listitem

In html list I can code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The li value attribute</h1>

<ol>
  <li value="100">Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li value="200">Water</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
  <li>Beer</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

The numbering are skipped:

[image]

How do I do that in Material ui List ?  I've tried sending in the value in sx but it does not work and I cannot find an option in ListItem that is eqivalent to value in html list.

Thanks.

Update: Thought value is not found in the Material UI API at https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/, I added it and I manage to "renumber" the list.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Thought value is not found in the Material UI API at https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/, I added it and I manage to "renumber" the list.